# Efficiently displaying number of days since ... in Odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8

Consider the following efficiency issue:

```
some_date = fields.Date(default="1999-01-01")

days_since_some_date = fields.Integer(compute='_compute_days')

@api.multi
def _compute_days(self):
    today = datetime.datetime.now().date()
    for r in self:
        r.days_since_some_date = (today - datetime.datetime.strptime(r.some_date, '%Y-%m-%d').days
```

If days_since_some_date is displayed in the tree view of some object, then this value is being recomputed on every single refresh and, throughout any given day, almost never changes. That is to say, this value increments by one each day and would only ever otherwise change if the date in the some_date field is manually changed.

One would ideally like to avoid recomputing this value on every refresh, but can't make it stored because then it wouldn't increment daily. Similarly, it does not merely depend on the some_date field making it a hybrid of something which depends on both the current date and the some_date field.

The question is, how might one who is bound to the Odoo framework go about having such a field without triggering unnecessary maintenance to a large recordset?

**Additional Thoughts**

1. One cannot simply make the field stored because it wouldn't increment daily.
2. One cannot make concrete dependencies on the field since it depends on both some_date (an attribute of the object) and the current_date (not an attribute of the object).
3. I could run an automated action to recompute the field daily, but it should also be re-evaluated whenever the some_date field is changed. In this sense, I'm assuming this solution would be to make the field stored, computed, depending on some_date and also forced to be recomputed on a daily schedule via automation. Is this something that might work?

Answer (score 0):

You could use an automated action of the `ir.cron` model, behaves like a linux cron job

basically you'll have something like this for your case

```
<openerp>
    <data noupdate="1">
        <record id="ir_cron_date" model="ir.cron">
            <field name="name">Date cron job</field>
            <field name="user_id" ref="base.user_root"/>
            <field name="interval_number">1</field>
            <field name="interval_type">days</field>
            <field name="numbercall">-1</field>
            <field eval="True" name="doall"/>
            <field eval="'your.model'" name="model"/>
            <field eval="'date_cron_function'" name="function"/>
        </record>
   </data>
</openerp>
```

though the docs don't say much about how it can be used

For a little reference checkout http://useopenerp.com/v8/model/ir-cron

i couldn't find it anywhere in the docs

Personally, i believe this is overkill recomputing the date anytime the form is loaded isn't an expensive operation for python, odoo or the server.

Comment: Including the calculation in a (once per day) cron job would certainly aid with the daily increment, but would I be able to make the compute function simultaneously depend on 'some_date' so that it is also updated immediately whenever this field is changed?

Comment: yes you can do that with the docorator `@api.onchange('some_date')`, anytime the field is changed you can manually re-compute and increment the date

Comment: Doesn't the onchange only edit the field for visibility in the UI? Wouldn't it be more appropriate to use @api.depends?

Comment: yeah you're right, i meant to say `@api.depends`. it's more appropriate because it would be triggered if the value of `some_date` changed via the form (when saving it) or from some other computation in another model, on the other hand `@api.onchange` would only be changed when the field is changed via the form in that model